# How do I get my userform VBA to copy and paste a specific row from a worksheet into another worksheet based on multiple complex conditions?

Tags: excel, vba

I have rudimentary VBA experience, but I have a specific problem which I need VBA to solve.

Here is my best attempt at explaining what I need VBA to do (with some context):

**Context on How the Spreadsheet Works**
I have a worksheet called 'Block Chain' which logs a large amount of data for a project every time a change is made to information associated with this project. For example, 'worksheet 1' is a place in which someone could change the 'project manager' associated with 'project a' amongst other things. The changes are made with userforms on various worksheets.

Every time *any* change is made to project information, *all* information associated with that project (including the new change) is stored on the 'Block Chain' worksheet in the next available row. This row will contain information like, 'project name', 'project sponsor', 'budget', and 'project manager' etc.

So let's say I change the 'project manager' from 'Steve' to 'Ben' for 'project a' on 'worksheet 1'. Once I have done this, the next available row in the 'Block Chain' worksheet (row 100, for example) will store all current information for 'project a'. The cell in the 'project manager' column on this row will say 'Ben', because this is now the project manager for project a.

Let's say, after a few months, I change the 'project manager' again from 'Ben' to 'John'. After this, the next available row in the 'Block Chain' worksheet (row 250, for example, since a few months have passed) will store all current information for 'project a'. The cell in the 'project manager' column on this row will now say 'John', because this is now the project manager for project a.

**What I Need VBA to Do**
This is the part I actually need help with. All the above already happens when a userform in the spreadsheet is submitted through VBA. I need to add some additional code which does something quite specific every time a userform in the spreadsheet is submitted.

Firstly, I want this code to scan the 'Block Chain' worksheet and find the last row of data for any given project and store this in a dynamic variable -- say, 'last-row-for-project'. In addition, I want this code to scan the 'Block Chain' worksheet and find the *penultimate* (second to last) row for any given project and store this in a dynamic variable -- say, 'penultimate-row-for-project'.

By way of example, for 'project a', 'last-row-for-project' is row 250, and 'penultimate-row-for-project' is row 100.

I then want the code to apply some conditions to these dynamic variables and perform some tasks depending on the outcome of these conditions.

*Here are the conditions:*

1. If 'cell in any given columns(x)' in 'last-row-for-project' **is not equal to** 'cell in the given columns(x)' in 'penultimate-row-for-project'
2. And 'cell in specified columns(y)' in 'last-row-for-project' **is equal to** 'specified value: NEW'

*And here is what I want the code to do if the conditions are TRUE:*

1. Copy 'last-row-for-project'
2. Paste 'last-row-for-project' into 'worksheets(z)'

**Note:** 'Worksheets(z)' will need to be worksheets that have equivalent names to 'columns(x)' in 'cell in any given columns(x)' (as specified in *condition 1* above). So 'worksheets(z)' is also a dynamic variable that could represent multiple worksheets, and therefore could result in the "Paste 'last-row-for-project'" action being applied to multiple worksheets.

So, this code will compare cells in ranges "columns(x):'last-row-for-project'" and "columns(x):'penultimate-row-for-project'" in the 'Block Chain' worksheet. If these cells are different, and if "column 1:'last-row-for-project' = NEW", then the code will copy 'last-row-for-project' and paste it in all the worksheets that have the same names as the columns in which there were different cells (between 'last-row-for-project' and 'penultimate-row-for-project').

To refer back to my initial example, the code would copy row 250 (provided *condition 2* is also TRUE), and paste it into the 'project manager' worksheet, because this is the name of the column in which the change was made for 'project a'. If I had also changed the 'project sponsor' for 'project a', I would want the code to **also** paste row 250 into the 'project sponsor' worksheet **as well as** the 'project manager' worksheet. This is why I say 'worksheets(z)' needs to be a dynamic variable that can store multiple spreadsheet within it.

I really do need help with this quite desperately, so please please let me know even if you know how *some* of this code would work. Thank you very much.

I have very little VBA experience. I have written out the pseudo code (as seen above) and I have tried to convert this into Visual Basic to no avail since I do not have VBA knowledge.

Comment: The data in your Block Chain spreadsheet seems like it should be in a database.  Especially if multiple users could make simultaneous changes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I could do this, but would this allow me to have a running database for changes made to projects from which I can make graphs and dashboards?

Comment: You keep the data in the database and then import it into your Excel spreadsheet(s) for Excel-type things like reporting, charts, etc.  Databases are good at managing data (especially for multiple users).  Excel is good at UI, analysis and presentation.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm just not sure how a database would make the data do what I need it to do as outlined in my question though

Comment: My observation about databases doesn't really have much to do with answering your question, it was more about data integrity for the first part (which you already have working in Excel).  As for your question (the stuff after "**What I Need VBA to do**"), you'd probably need VBA to do it in Excel, with or without a database.  It's hard to answer that without some example code as a starting place, and/or specifics about where the data in the sheet begins or ends (or how that is determined), etc.